# Let $f$ be holomorphic, $f(\overline{z})$ is holomorphic if and only if $f(z)$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic, $f(\overline{z})$ is holomorphic if and only if $f(z)$ is constant.

My proof: Let $$f(\overline{z})=\Sigma a_n(\overline{z}-z_0)^n$$ and we know the series converges uniformly as $|z|=|\overline{z}|$ thus we can take the derivative term wise, but each term for $n>0$ is not differentiable as $\overline{z}$ is not differentiable. Thus the limit does not exist and the function is not differentiable. Unless $f$ is a constant.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, a sequence of non-holomorphic functions can converge uniformly to a holomorphic function.

Comment: By assumption $z \mapsto f(\bar{z})$ is holomorphic so it must be differentiable.

Comment: @copper.hat, is there a typo in your comment?

Comment: @paulgarrett: Thanks, spellling is not a string point fo rme.

Comment: @copper.hat ... :)

Comment: The above approach can be made to work, but it boils down to showing that for any $z_0$ the corresponding $a_1$ must be zero otherwise $z \mapsto f(\bar{z})$ is not differentiable.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this line of reasoning will get you there.  It is possible for the sum of two non-differentiable functions to be differentiable. Consider $f(z) = {\rm Re}(z)$ and $g(z) = i{\rm Im}(z)$. Neither is differentiable, but their sum $f(z) + g(z) =z$ is differentiable.

Instead, why not use the Cauchy-Riemann equations? Writing $f(x+iy)= u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, what do the Cauchy-Riemann equations tell you if $f(z)$ is differentiable? What do they tell you if $f(\bar z) =u(x,-y)+iv(x,-y)$ is differentiable?

---

**Edit:** In view of the comments below, let me give you an example of an **infinite series** of functions that is uniformly convergent and where the limit is differentiable, yet the individual terms are not differentiable.

Consider
$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(z),$
where $
f_{2k}(z) = {\rm Re}(z^k),$ and $f_{2k + 1}(z) = i {\rm Im}(z^k)
$. On the closed ball $\overline{B(0, r)}$ (for $0 < r < 1$), this series converges uniformly to $ 1 / (1 - z)$.

Yet none of the individual terms (i.e. none of the $f_n(z)$'s) are differentiable.

Comment: I don't think I am using the fact that sum of two non differentiable functions is not differentiable. I am using the fact that uniform convergence allows me to take the limit termwise. But termwise that limit does not exist. I think that is different?

Comment: But the termwise limit *exits*! It is $f\left(\overline z\right)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I mean the termwise derivative.

Comment: Then you are claiming that if several functions are not differentiable, then neither is their sum. But this answer shows that you are wrong.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am not trying to be difficult but I see the distinction. Like take the derivative termwise of $\overline{z}-\overline{z}$ you would say you cannot, the terms are not differentiable, even though the function itself is. I am saying in the case of series like this, we can do it termwise, and should still get the right answer. But termwise, the derivative does not exist.

Comment: The derivative exists by assumption. What you need to show is that it is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Use the identity theorem.

Let $\phi(z) = f(z)-f(\bar{z})$, note that $\phi(x) = 0$ for $x$ real and so $\phi = 0$.

Hence $f(z) = f(\bar{z})$.

Since ${f(x+it) -f(x) \over it} = {f(x-it) -f(x) \over it} $ we see
that $f'(x) = 0$ for $x$ real and so $f' = 0$.

Hence $f$ is a constant.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why the equality implies the derivative is 0?

Comment: Compute the limit of the quotients above to get $f'(x)=-f'(x)$.

Comment: I am sorry i am saying this so late, but I was very busy. I still do not see how you got that. I think both side should be equal to $f'(x)$. the negative sign is just means we approach $0$ from the opposite side, no?

Comment: No. Just compute the derivative as above. $\lim_{t \to 0} {f(x+it) -f(x) \over it} = f'(x)$. $\lim_{t\to 0} {f(x-it) -f(x) \over it} = - \lim_{t\to 0} {f(x-it) -f(x) \over -it} = - f'(x)$.

Comment: Are you computing the real derivative?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. The definition is $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} {f(x+h)-f(x) \over h}$. In the first case $h=it$, in the second $h=-it$.

Comment: Yes exactly, then since $f$ is holomorphic, both limits must be equal. Sorry I am just confused.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Think about it in terms of $\Bbb R^2$.

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
$$
and
$$
f(z)=f(x+iy)=:g(x,y)\\
f(\bar z)=f(x-iy)=:h(x,y)
$$
Now your problem can be restated as:
$$
\frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)h(x,y)=0
$$
iff $g$ is constant.